# How are values returned from a function using the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, calling-convention

Assume this code:

```c
int add(int a, int b){
    int c = a+b;
    return c;
}

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", add(3,4));
}
```

The following is usually how this is implemented in assembly:

1. push `4` to stack
2. push `3` to stack
3. push return address which is the address of the next instruction, `print()` to stack
4. call `add`
5. do addition and push `c` on the stack
6. pop `c` from stack (?)
7. return to `main`

So what happens to the return value? It can't be on the `add` frame as that will be cleared at the end. Does it get put onto the stack of `main`?

Let's assume the values are pushed to the stack and not to a register.

Comment: Return values are usually sitting in a register. But depends on ABI of course..

Comment: Assume it's a struct instance being returned, it can't be on the register then.

Comment: For such types a hidden pointer is passed in. Consult ABI documentation for details and/or examine compiler generated assembly code.

Comment: You can check e.g. on Godbolt.com , https://godbolt.org/z/Nimcge , `int` is being returned in `eax` usually

Comment: If you were designing a protocol for how functions are called and how they return values, and you do not use a register to return values, then logical choices include either designating a place in the caller’s stack frame where the return value will be written or having the caller pass an address where the return value will be written. For example, if a four-byte `int` is expected to be returned, the caller might make space on the stack for it, then execute the call instruction. The called routine would write its return value into that reserved space, higher than the stack pointer.

Comment: In common ABIs, when a function return type is for a large object, perhaps a structure of several hundred bytes, the calling function passes a pointer to space. This pointer does not appear in the explicit arguments in the source code; it is passed in a manner “hidden” from the regular source code. The called function uses that pointer to write the result.

Comment: Which assembler? Please add relevant system tags such as for example x86. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info for tag usage. When mixing C and assembler, the ABI calling convention also matters, so you must also specify compiler and OS (if any).

Comment: For large struct return, the usual way is by adding a hidden output-pointer arg: [Purpose of rdi register for no argument function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60510764)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the architecture and calling convention. In x86-32 just about every calling convention has the return value in `eax` or `edx:eax` for 64-bit results. So your `add` function might have the instructions:

```
mov eax, dword ptr [esp+4] ; put 1st arg in eax
add eax, dword ptr [esp+8] ; add eax with 2nd arg
ret                        ; return
```

No extra work is needed since the return value is already supposed to be in `eax`.

That said you aren't going to find a "general case" answer for this unless you are asking about a specific architecture, and even then, there can be multiple different calling conventions on it.