# Purpose of rdi register for no argument function

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

Consider this simple function:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  int e;
  int f;
};

Foo foo() {
  Foo f;
  f.a = 1;
  f.b = 2;
  f.c = 3;
  f.d = 4;
  f.e = 5;
  f.f = 6;

  return f;
}
```

It generates the following assembly:

```
0000000000400500 <foo()>:
  400500:       48 ba 01 00 00 00 02    movabs rdx,0x200000001
  400507:       00 00 00 
  40050a:       48 b9 03 00 00 00 04    movabs rcx,0x400000003
  400511:       00 00 00 
  400514:       48 be 05 00 00 00 06    movabs rsi,0x600000005
  40051b:       00 00 00 
  40051e:       48 89 17                mov    QWORD PTR [rdi],rdx
  400521:       48 89 4f 08             mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x8],rcx
  400525:       48 89 77 10             mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x10],rsi
  400529:       48 89 f8                mov    rax,rdi
  40052c:       c3                      ret    
  40052d:       0f 1f 00                nop    DWORD PTR [rax]
```

Based on the assembly, I understand that the caller created space for `Foo` on its stack, and passed that information in `rdi` to the callee.

I am trying to find documentation for this convention. [Calling convention in linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) states that `rdi` contains the first integer argument. In this case, `foo` doesn't have any arguments.

Moreover, if I make `foo` take one integer argument, that is now passed as `rsi` (register for second argument) with rdi used for address of the return object.

Can anyone provide some documentation and clarity on how `rdi` is used in system V ABI?

Comment: Internally transform `Foo foo()` by `void foo(Foo& output)`?

Comment: You should also disassemble a call to `foo` as in `Foo x = foo();`.

Comment: @ErikEidt I did do that. And the address was indeed passed in rdi. I was curious about the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See section *3.2.3 Parameter Passing* in the [ABI docs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) which says:

> If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the
>   return value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it
>   were the first argument to the function. In effect, this address
>   becomes a "hidden" first argument.
>
> On return %rax will contain the address that has been passed in by the
>   caller in %rdi.